# How do I use a Less than or greater than symble in the WHERE statement with a SUM feature

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want it to list the records if the total number of Yes's are less than 5.

I am getting an error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in sub query contained in a HAVING clause or select list , and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

I want to list students who are in WCM103, and have attended less than 5 classes.

Comment: Aggregate functions doesn't work with where clause.

Comment: Could you post the structure and data types of the ATTENDANCE table please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like:

```
WITH att
  AS (SELECT studentID, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN attStatus = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as att_count
        FROM attendance
       GROUP BY studentID)
SELECT *
  FROM Attendance a 
 INNER JOIN Student s USING (studentID)
 INNER JOIN att USING (studentID)
 WHERE att.att_count < 5
   AND a.unitcode = 'SIT103';
```

work for you?

You could select the columns from STUDENT and ATTENDANCE you need etc.

EDIT: I don't have a SQL interface in front of me tody so some of the SQL might need tweaking.

David, in light of the new info, try the following:

```
WITH att
  AS (SELECT unitcode,
             studentID, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN attStatus = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as att_count
        FROM attendance
       WHERE attdate < TO_DATE('07/08/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
       GROUP BY unitcode,
                studentID)
SELECT *
  FROM Student s
 INNER JOIN att USING (studentID)
 WHERE att.unitcode = 'SIT103'
   AND att.att_count < 5;
```

I have SQL*Plus running again now. I just ran:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  studentid NUMBER,
  student_name VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE attendance (
  studentid NUMBER,
  unitcode VARCHAR2(10),
  attdate  DATE,
  attstatus VARCHAR2(5)
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES (2106,'Jo Bloggs');
INSERT INTO student VALUES (2108,'Jo Schmoe');

INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (2106, 'SIT103', TO_DATE('05/06/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'No');
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (2106, 'SIT103', TO_DATE('07/07/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Yes');
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (2106, 'SIT103', TO_DATE('10/05/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Yes');
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (2108, 'SIT203', TO_DATE('05/05/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Yes');

WITH att
  AS (SELECT unitcode,
             studentID, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN attStatus = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as att_count
        FROM attendance
       WHERE attdate < TO_DATE('07/08/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
       GROUP BY unitcode,
                studentID)
SELECT studentid,
       student_name,
       unitcode
  FROM Student s
 INNER JOIN att USING (studentID)
 WHERE att.unitcode = 'SIT103'
   AND att.att_count < 5;
```

and got:

```
STUDENTID STUDENT_NAME UNITCODE
2106         Jo Schmoe    SIT103
```

Which is correct isn't it?

Comment: YES thank you .. How would i be able to add a less than statement for the DATE .

Comment: EG: Attended less than 2 classes before 7/8/2011

Comment: If you are limiting by date in your aggregation (which I think you will be) then add the extra clause to a WHERE clause in the WITH statement that groups the ATTENDANCE records.

Comment: Im not an expert with this, could you help me out?

Comment: Come to think of it you might need to add the unitcode to a WHERE clause in the WITH statement too and add unitcode to the group by too. (I wish i had a SQL interface with me).

Comment: If you update your post, i can try it and post the error code. We can work together :)

Comment: So far everything works. I just want to add a date constraint as well.

Comment: What error? It'd be helpful to post what the error is as I can't test it myself at the moment.

Comment: 'TO_DATE' is not recognized   built in Function name. 'studentID' is not recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function , ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90

Comment: What version of Oracle DB are you using? What SQL interface are you running this through?

Comment: Um im not sure what ver of oracle, but SQL server 2005

Comment: There's the problem. In your question tags, you have "ORACLE" as one of the tags so the code I have given you is Oracle specific. The errors you are getting are due to you running it on SQL Server. I am not a SQL Server T-SQL developer so I can't convert it for you but if you post another question with the tag SQL SERVER then you should get an answer. Sorry I can't be more help...

Answer (score 1):

To use having, you have to have a group by clause, the group by is then executed and the having acts as a filter after the query has been aggregated.

Not sure you want to do a sum, without seeing the data in the tables but you should be able to do a count of the number of yes in the attendance table and then the having will list those that meet the criteria

Try something like this (oracle SQL syntax)

```
SELECT s.studentname, count(*)
  FROM student s, attendance a
 WHERE s.studentid=a.studentid
   AND a.class='SIT108'
   AND a.status='Y'
 GROUP BY s.studentname
HAVING COUNT(*)<5
```

or with ANSI syntax

```
SELECT s.studentname, count(*)
  FROM student s
  LEFT INNER JOIN attendance a
    ON s.studentid=a.studentid
 WHERE a.class='SIT108'
   AND a.status='Y'
 GROUP BY s.studentname
HAVING COUNT(*)<5
```

You can omit the count(*) on the top line as well if you just want a list of names

```
SELECT s.studentname
  FROM student s
  LEFT INNER JOIN attendance a
    ON s.studentid=a.studentid
 WHERE a.class='SIT108'
   AND a.status='Y'
 GROUP BY s.studentname
HAVING COUNT(*)<5
```

Add whatever additional where clauses or joins you need

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `WHERE` with `HAVING` as in the following:

```
SELECT        * 
FROM            Attendance AS a INNER JOIN
                         Student AS s ON a.studentID = s.studentID
HAVING        (SUM(CASE WHEN attStatus = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 5)
```

Comment: You have to have a group by clause to be able to use having